# How to remove red eye from image in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, image-processing, iphone-sdk-3.0

I want to remove red eye effect form photo but not get any sample can any one help me with working demo code or code snippet?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use below `category` of `UIImage` :

```
@interface UIImage (Utitlities)
  -(UIImage*)redEyeCorrection;
@end
```

---

```
@implementation UIImage (Utitlities)
  -(UIImage*)redEyeCorrection
  {
    CIImage *ciImage = [[CIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:self.CGImage];

    // Get the filters and apply them to the image
    NSArray* filters = [ciImage autoAdjustmentFiltersWithOptions:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:kCIImageAutoAdjustEnhance]];
    for (CIFilter* filter in filters)
    {
      [filter setValue:ciImage forKey:kCIInputImageKey];
      ciImage = filter.outputImage;
    }

    // Create the corrected image
    CIContext* ctx = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
    CGImageRef cgImage = [ctx createCGImage:ciImage fromRect:[ciImage extent]];
    UIImage* final = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImage];
    CGImageRelease(cgImage);
    return final;
  }
@end
```

**Usage**: Sample code given below

```
 UIImage *redEyeImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"redEye.jpg"];

if (redEyeImage) {
    UIImage *newRemovedRedEyeImage = [redEyeImage redEyeCorrection];
    if (newRemovedRedEyeImage) {
        imgView.image = newRemovedRedEyeImage;
    }
}
```

Refer [NYXImagesKit UIImage Enhancing](https://github.com/Nyx0uf/NYXImagesKit/blob/master/Categories/UIImage%2BEnhancing.m) link

Comment: Please provide some details like in which version or in which situation it doesnot work???

Comment: can you please check now as i made some changes

Comment: @Paresh Nasadiya: It is not working. I have installed the Pod for same but it is not remove the Red eye correction. Please suggest!

Comment: @PareshNavadiya it is not working. Can you help to solve the problem?

Comment: @PareshNavadiya not working with all cases, please help