# Code for red eye removal in ios7

Tags: ios

How to remove red eye from an image in ios7,by clicking on each eye,please help I don't want to use Aviary sdk and not getting enough reference to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

[Following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13249013/how-to-remove-red-eye-from-image-in-iphone) should help. It uses system provided CoreImage framework. You can detect eye region by using the same framework and when you detect tapping in that region, perform red eye removal.

Comment: Thaks I have already applied this code,it removes red eye from whole image,but I want to remove by clicking on each single eye