# How to remove RedEye from image?

Tags: ios

I know this question was too vague .Actually I need to remove redEye of picked image .I have searched many links but I'm not getting the correct..I have gone through this link but i'm not getting
[How to remove red eye from image in iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13249013/how-to-remove-red-eye-from-image-in-iphone)

Please if anyone knows the easy way reply me.Thanks In advance

Comment: Documentation is always a good start yeah? https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_autoadjustment/ci_autoadjustmentSAVE.html

Comment: yes.I know that But what's the filter that should be used for removing RedEye?

Comment: It tells you in the documentation. Try reading it next time: 

"The auto enhancement API has only two methods: autoAdjustmentFilters and autoAdjustmentFiltersWithOptions:. In most cases, you’ll want to use the method that provides an options dictionary.

You can set these options:

The image orientation, which is important for the CIRedEyeCorrection and CIFaceBalance filters, so that Core Image can find faces accurately.
Whether to apply only red eye correction. (Set kCIImageAutoAdjustEnhance to false.)"

Comment: I tried that one But I'm getting NSPlaceholderDictionary exception...:(

Comment: NSPlaceholderDictionary usually means your passing a nil object to the Dictionary. FYI. Usually.

Comment: Now It's working fine for me ...Can I Know how to implement to focus a particular selected area and keeping remaining part blurred?

Comment: Your not going to like my answer, but if you read the documentation it goes through the steps of creating a custom filter. I would suggest, and not to be rude, that this project may be out of your grasp right now, so maybe look into existing frameworks or libraries already built by other developers you can implement. Places like github etc https://github.com/search?utf8=✓&q=iOS+image+edit&type=Repositories&ref=searchresults

Comment: when I'm using CIBloom filter to smoothen my image ,I'm not getting correct output