# Red Eye Correction

Tags: objective-c, filter, face-detection

To add red eye correction effect, I had followed this link:

[How to remove red eye from image in iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13249013/how-to-remove-red-eye-from-image-in-iphone)

Installed above library via pods. Added following code in my class.

```
UIImage *redEyeImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Userimage"];

if (redEyeImage) {
    UIImage *newRemovedRedEyeImage = [redEyeImage redEyeCorrection];
    if (newRemovedRedEyeImage) {
        imgView.image = newRemovedRedEyeImage;
    }
}
```

but I didn't get the required output. Is there anything I am missing? Or is there any other library to implement this concept. Please suggest.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that the image name has been typed correctly? Can you tell me whether the `if` statement executes?

Comment: Yeah, if statement is executing. But result remains same

Answer (score 0):

You could set breakpoints on the lines right after both if statements and then run your app and see if they're being hit (perhaps `redEyeImage` doesn't exist or `newRemovedRedEyeImage` doesn't.

Another simple way to check is:

```
UIImage *redEyeImage;
UIImage *newRemovedRedEyeImage;

redEyeImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Userimage"];

if (redEyeImage) {
    newRemovedRedEyeImage = [redEyeImage redEyeCorrection];
    if (newRemovedRedEyeImage) {
        imgView.image = newRemovedRedEyeImage;
    }
}

NSLog(@"redEyeImage: %@", (redEyeImage != nil ? @"exists" : @"nil"));
NSLog(@"newRemovedRedEyeImage: %@", (newRemovedRedEyeImage != nil ? @"exists" : @"nil"));
```

then run this and see what the two logs at the bottom print.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I resolved this issue with following code:

```
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"images.png"];
CIImage *image = [[CIImage alloc]initWithImage:img];
NSLog(@"after ciimage: %@", kCIImageAutoAdjustEnhance);
NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"NO" forKey:kCIImageAutoAdjustEnhance];
NSLog(@"options: %@", options);
NSArray *adjustments = [image autoAdjustmentFiltersWithOptions:options];
NSLog(@"adjustments: %@  ", adjustments);

for (CIFilter * filter in adjustments)
{
    [filter setValue:image forKey:kCIInputImageKey];
    image = filter.outputImage;
}
CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
CGImageRef cgImage = [context createCGImage:image fromRect:image.extent];
UIImage *enhancedImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:cgImage];
CGImageRelease(cgImage);
self.img.image = enhancedImage;
```